# Is there a way to delete the leading numbers only from those elements that start with a number followed by a period?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have data in this format:

```
    1. New York Times - USA
    2. Guardian - UK
    Der Spiegel - Germany
    3. Le Monde - France
    Dagen - Denmark (12.6.2002)
    Norga-i-Dag (2) - Norway
```

I want to end up with newspaper values of:

```
    New York Times
    Guardian
    Der Spiegel
    Le Monde
    Dagen
    Norga-i-Dag
```

I'm using this code to parse out the `newspaper` and `country` values:

```
    String newspaper = "";
    String country = "";
    int hyphenIndex = unparsedText.indexOf("-");
    if (hyphenIndex > -1)
    {
        newspaper = unparsedText.substring(0, hyphenIndex);
    }
    country = unparsedText.substring(hyphenIndex + 1, unparsedText.length());
    country = country.trim();
```

**Is there a way to delete the leading numbers only from those elements that start with a number followed by a period:**

```
    1. New York Times
    2. Guardian
    3. Le Monde
```

In other words this would be fine as a compromise:

```
    . New York Times - USA
    . Guardian - UK
    Der Spiegel - Germany
    . Le Monde - France
    Dagen - Denmark (12.6.2002)
    Norga-i-Dag (2) - Norway
```

**I want to avoid creating problems for elements like these that also contain numbers and/or periods:**

```
    Dagen - Denmark (12.6.2002)
    Norga-i-Dag (2) - Norway
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155843/whats-the-simplest-way-to-remove-extraneous-leading-numbers

Answer (score 2):

try this to remove at least one digit, followed by a period and any number of spaces.

```
String text = unparsedText.replace("^[0-9]+\\. *", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you'll get a flood of answers shortly :-).  In the mean time I think you'll benefit from the [RegEx tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).  Hint: . is a special character in regex

Answer (score 1):

This will remove any digits followed by a period followed by a space, i.e. `11.`. **NOTE:** It would be best if `unparsedText` were each line, as otherwise this may replace items you want to keep.

```
unparsedText.replaceAll('\\d+\.\\s+', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+\\.\\s*", "");
```

should do.

It will delete a number, a dot and optional spaces, but only at the start of a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to directly transform your input to output:

```
String result = input.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+\\.\\s*|-(?!.*-)\\s*.*?$", "");
```

[**Code In Action**](http://www.ideone.com/exZ7R)